# How to prevent useless update requests in `useEffect` without using additional variables

Tags: reactjs, optimization, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to do this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!datasetsState.list.length) {
      dispatch({ type: DatasetsActionTypes.FETCH, payload: {} });
    }
  }, [datasetsState, dispatch]);
```

but `dispatch({ type: DatasetsActionTypes.FETCH, payload: {} });` causes update of `datasetsState` which will cause forever loop if `datasetsState.list` stay empty after response

One of the solutions to my problem is to remove `datasetsState` from the dependency array, but I will get react `exhaustive-deps` warning which I want to avoid.

And the following code will work for me also and don't cause any warnings. But it is an ugly and complex solution for a pretty common problem I think.

```
const [isDoneOnce, setIsDoneOnce] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isDoneOnce) {
      return;
    }
    if (!datasetsState.list.length) {
      dispatch({ type: DatasetsActionTypes.FETCH, payload: {} });
    }
    setIsDoneOnce(true);
  }, [datasetsState, dispatch]);
```

How can I prevent `useEffect` from updating without using additional variables like `isDoneOnce` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to depend on the actual value used inside useEffect, e.g.:

```
const len = datasetsState.list.length

useEffect(() => {
  if (!len) {
    dispatch(...)
  }
}, [len, dispatch])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a "global" variable or a reference.

Which one to choose depends on the context, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57444430/7882470) about the differences.

**TL;DR** - Depends on the context of **"run once"**, *application life* or *component's life*.

#### Reference:

```
const App = () => {
  const isDoneRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isDoneRef.current) {
      dispatch({ type: DatasetsActionTypes.FETCH, payload: {} });
      isDoneRef.current = true;
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <></>;
};
```

#### Variable:

```
let isDoneGlobal = false;

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isDoneGlobal) {
      dispatch({ type: DatasetsActionTypes.FETCH, payload: {} });
      isDoneGlobal = true;
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <></>;
};
```