# Should I use state at all for a variable that does not affect rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. In the code below, how do I make the value of `status` variable change immediately after `setStatus(!status)`? I understand that state updates in React are batched, therefore I am using the `useEffect` with callback, but still the value of `status` is logged as `false` upon first button click (as if it did not change immediately).
2. Considering that the app rendering is not in any way dependent on the `status` variable (actually, I would even prefer that the changes of this variable do not trigger a render), would it be a bad practice to not use `useEffect` at all and make `status` a "normal" variable instead, assigned like `status = true`?

```js
function App() {

  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => toggleStatus, [status])

  function onClickHandler() {
    toggleStatus()
    console.log(status)
  }

  function toggleStatus() {
    setStatus(!status)
  }

  return ( 
    <div>
        <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Toggle & log status</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( < App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@^16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: PLease check this https://brewhouse.io/blog/2015/03/24/best-practices-for-component-state-in-reactjs.html . For understanding when to use the state and when not

Comment: Whenever you change the value of status with setStatus the component will render, that's exactly the role of useState() hook;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the code below, how do I make the value of status variable change immediately after `setStatus(!status)`?

You can't make state to change immediately as changing state is async.

> I would even prefer that the changes of this variable do not trigger a render), would it be bad practice to not use `useEffect` at all and make status a "normal" variable instead, assigned like status = true?

First, check [what are the use cases for `useEffect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947).

About making a "normal" variable instead, its indeed a bad practice:

```
const Component = () => {
   let variable = ...;
   return <>...</>
}
```

That's because, on every render, such variables will re-assigned (because the body of the function component executed on every render). **Usually**, it is not the desired behavior.

Instead, you want to use a reference with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). See [what is the difference between `useRef` and a variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444154/why-need-useref-to-contain-mutable-variable-but-not-define-variable-outside-the/57444430#57444430)

Changing the reference value won't trigger a render, therefore won't update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you click `onClickHandler` triggered ==> `toggleStatus` and `console.log(status)` are triggered synchronously (`setStatus(!status)` of toggleStatus is triggered asynchronously. So you see `false` is logged.
   AND you are using `useEffect` incorrectly. `React.useEffect(() => toggleStatus, [status])` mean the first argument of `useEffect` return `toggleStatus` function, that is the [cleanup action of `useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)

Try this to see status logged

```
React.useEffect(() =>{
  //you can see true after first click here
  console.log(status)
}, [status])
```

2. If you want to change `status` immediately and don't re-render the component, you would use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) instead

Answer (score 1):

I will comment your code

```js
function App() {

  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => toggleStatus, [status]) // here you are toggle the status again when the status change 

  function onClickHandler() {
    toggleStatus()
    console.log(status)
  }

  function toggleStatus() {
    setStatus(!status) // here you can do setStatus(prevStatus => !prevStatus)
  }

  return ( 
    <div>
        <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Toggle & log status</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( < App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@^16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can try with a console.log(status) inside the useEffect and see if everything its ok.

```
React.useEffect(() => console.log(status), [status])
```

Now talking about the second point, in my opinion that is not a bad practice. According to React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state):

> The state contains data specific to this component that may change
> over time. [...] If you don't use it in render(), it shouldn't be in
> the state. For example, you can put timer IDs directly on the
> instance.

Answer (score 1):

React states are used to track application state and re-render the app, when this underlying state changes.

Now, if you do not want a re-render, when `status` changes, you should declare `status` as a regular variable.

You can still use the `useEffect` react hook, if you want. And you can initialize `status` here. `useEffect` is called the component is mounted/rendered on the browser DOM

Comment: Notice that every time you re-render all regular variables are reset.