# Change text every 3 seconds React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to change my text every 3 seconds using useEffect() and setInterval(). Right now it only changes the text ONE time then it doesn't change it anymore.
What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm using the library "react-spring"

```
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      switch (toggle) {
        case false: setToggle(true)
        break;
        case true: setToggle(false)
        break;
      }
    }, 3000);
  }, [])

{transitions.map(({ item, props }) => item
  ? <animated.div style={props}>Text that changes #1</animated.div>
  : <animated.div style={props}>Text that changes #2</animated.div>)}
```

Comment: You're closing over the `toggle` state inside of your setInterval callback, maybe consider using useInterval hook by Dan: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/ (or perhaps a ref). Also worth looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65489257/react-setinterval-behavior/65489303#65489303) posted yesterday and. its answer

Comment: Try something like this instead: `useEffect(() => { setTimeout(() => setToggle(prevToggle => !prevToggle), 3000) }, [toggle]);` the timed out function should get the new toggle value each time

Comment: It actually worked when i removed the [toggle] in the end of useEffect function. Why is that? I thought that it should listen to toggle variable to work? @Jayce444

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() =>  {
        setToggle((toggle) => !toggle)
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
}, []);
```

Important points:

1. The dependency array `[]` should be empty. This way you ensure that you're gonna execute this effect only on the initial mounting of the component. You need only a single interval and its creation and destruction are not dependent on a single variable but the component itself. If you put `toggle` in the dependency array, you will run this effect every time the variable changes thus effectively making YET ANOTHER interval on every 3 seconds. If you did supply a clean-up function, this would still work but it would be more like a `setTimeout`. However, in your case (without a clean-up function), this will simply introduce infinite number of intervals which will compete with each other.
2. You have to supply an updater function to `setToggle` instead of a simple value. This ensures that you're using the most current state for the update and not the stale one in the closure. If you simply provide a value, the interval is making a closure over your initial value and thus updating it. In this way, you will always update the initial `false` to `true` and this will repeat forever, leaving you with a "constant" `true` value.
3. As you're using an interval, you should provide a clean-up function to the `useEffect` to clear the interval on component dismount. This is **very** important as skipping this part will introduce memory leaks and also bugs as you'll try to update a component even after its dismount from the DOM.

Comment: did you mean to write `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => setToggle((prevToggle) => !prevToggle), 3000);
}, [toggle]);
```

Comment: Check my comment under the others! It worked when i removed [toggle]