# Update value in span periodically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

React/JS newbie here.

I've got a simple react app with the page fetching a number from `ItemCounter` API-Gateway. The code works right now and it's able to fetch a value from the lambda/apig url.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Stats = () => {
  const [ItemsSupplied, setItemsSupplied] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(async () => {
    signIn();
  }, []);

  async function signIn() {
    // Async Signin functions and calls, followed by getData() call
    getData();
  }

  async function getData() {
    let url = "https://re1szvliqk.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ItemCounter";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const number = await response.json();
    setItemsSupplied(number);
  }
  return (
    <div>
        <span> Items Supplied: {ItemsSupplied} </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Stats;
```

I'm looking for a way to refresh/update this value periodically, let's say every 5 seconds, but couldn't figure it out.

Tried this: [Change text every 3 seconds React useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504562/change-text-every-3-seconds-react-useeffect), but couldn't merge this with my page and ran into errors. Errors had something to do with the fact that `signIn()` and consequently `getData()` are already being called in a `useEffect()`.

Hoping someone can help me out, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more `useEffect` inside which you need to set an interval for every 5 seconds.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Stats = () => {
  const [ItemsSupplied, setItemsSupplied] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    signIn();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = setInterval(()=>getData(),5000)
    return ()=>clearInterval(timer)
  },[ItemsSupplied]);

  async function signIn() {
    // Async Signin functions and calls, followed by getData() call
    getData();
  }

  async function getData() {
    let url = "https://re1szvliqk.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ItemCounter";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const number = await response.json();
    setItemsSupplied(number);
  }
  return (
    <div>
        <span> Items Supplied: {ItemsSupplied} </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Stats;
```