# creating timer with react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to have a countdown timer that counts from 60 to zero when the stage of program reaches two. Here's my code:

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(60)
useEffect(() => {
        if (stage === 2) {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                console.log(timer)
                setTimer(timer - 1)
                if (timer === 1) {
                    clearInterval(interval)
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    }, [stage])
```

and i have a div like below that just shows the counter value

```
<div>{timer}</div>
```

in my setInterval, when i use `console.log(timer)` it always prints out 60. But inside the div, the value starts with 60 and in the next second it will always be 59.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: you need to set the state and use the state so that component renders.

Comment: You are `console.log`ing before you `-1` from the timer, so even if it was synchronous it would print out 60. But as `setTimer` is asynchronous, you can't rely on the log ever showing the new value immediately, you would need an effect listening for changes to `timer`.

Comment: i know that. All i'm saying is, why the state won't get updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on `time === 60` value, use [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) instead.

For the same reason, you should have another `useEffect` for canceling the interval:

```
const intervalId = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  if (stage === 2) {
    intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((prevTimer) => prevTimer - 1);
    }, 1000);
  }
}, [stage]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(timer);
  if (timer === 1) {
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
  }
}, [timer]);
```

Check similar question: [`setInterval` counter common mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65489257/react-setinterval-behavior/65489303#65489303).