# Interaction between useEffect react and setInterval

Tags: reactjs, state, setinterval, use-effect

I am having a hard time understanding how useEffect works. Like the code below,
The count1 inside setInterval will always be 0 and useEffect never reaches the count2.
Meaning, after the first render, useEffect runs and it goes inside setInterval and never leaves, so how does the count in h1 still get updated? If it never gets out of useEffect. I thought state changes will always trigger a re-render thus trigger another useEffect. Maybe I am missing something. Please help. Thank you!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Timer() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCount((count) => count + 1);
      console.log("count1" + count);
    }, 1000);
    console.log("count2" + count);
  }, []);

  return <h1>I've rendered {count} times!</h1>;
}

export default Timer;
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542264/how-to-setinterval-for-every-5-second-render-with-react-hook-useeffect-in-react

Comment: There are plenty duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65489257/react-setinterval-behavior/65489303#65489303

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to note here is that `count` is a **local** variable.

Every time the `Timer` function gets called, it has a new `count` variable belonging to that invocation (which gets assigned a value by `useState`.

The **first** time the `Timer` function is called, the `useEffect` runs and the arrow function passed to `setInterval` forms a **closure** around that instance of `count`.

So every time the interval ticks, it logs the same value of `count`.

---

Meanwhile the callback function passed to `setCount` gets the **latest** value of `count` from the state, so it can be incremented there.

If you had just done: `setCount(count + 1);` then you would be reading the closed over `count` and constantly setting it to `0 + 1`.

---

And time `Timer` gets called it has a **new** `count` with the latest value stored in the state.

Answer (score 0):

The things you should fix:

- You are using count variable inside the useEffect, but you have not put it inside the dependency array of the hook, that's way your console.log will always display old value.
- You are not clearing interval, you are leaking resources:
  [How to setInterval for every 5 second render with React hook useEffect in React Native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542264/how-to-setinterval-for-every-5-second-render-with-react-hook-useeffect-in-react)